# What are the best practises for generating loopback users from Azure Active Directory on login (react-native application)?

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, loopbackjs, expo, loopback

I have a react-native application with the expo sdk, using loopback 3 as my backend, which I'm trying to add Azure Active Directory authorization and authentication to, so that my users can login with their work email and password.

I'm having with how I even do this and what technologies to use.

Currently I have a button which opens the browser and can authenticate and authorise a user to make a quick graph api call and fetch their user data, but I don't have a clue what to actually do with this information

If someone has done this before and just point me in the right direction that would be great. I have gone over a bunch of docs but just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your app makes a token request to the azure ad, after entering the user credential, your app uses the acquired token to access the graph api and then the graph api return the related resource.

For you tried, you could refer to oauth2.0 code grant flow, on [v1 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) or [v2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

For using token to call  ms graph api, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph).

Comment: This I figured out but the problem is I can't authorize and authenticate my loopback application with just the azure login. On the front end I can let them authenticate on with their azure account and return their account info but they still have to use that info and choose a password specifically for my app.

It's this last step I'm trying to cut out if you can understand me. I want them to be able to press a button, and authenticate and authorize them on loopback with one login, without them having to manually create an account

Comment: @PieterDirix did you already found a solution to this problem? I am trying to setup a loopback 4 app to work with Azure AD and am looking for example implementations.