# Loopback 4 implementing Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, loopback4

I am currently building a microservice that is responsible to communicate with Microsoft Graph, I have already made one with Loopback 3 and this was not a problem.
Except now, I am trying to do the same thing but with Loopback 4, but since the language changes from JavaScript to TypeScript I don't know if it's still possible to achieve this.

This was the code I used for Loopback 3 in my root server file:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const erouter = require('express').Router();
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;
const request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');
const graph = require('./graph.service');
const getBookings = require('./getBookings.service');
const cors = require('cors');
var compression = require('compression');

module.exports = function(server) {
    // Install a `/` route that returns server status
    var router = server.loopback.Router();
    router.get('/', server.loopback.status());

    // Configure simple-oauth2
    const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create({
        client: {
            id: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
            secret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD
        },
        auth: {
            tokenHost: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY,
            authorizePath: process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT,
            tokenPath: process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT
        }
    });

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        var MSUser = server.models.MSUser;
        var id = user.profile.oid;
        MSUser.find({ where: { oid: id } }, function(err, msu) {
            if (err) return done(err, null);
            if (!msu) {
                MSUser.create(user);
            } else {
                done(null, id);
            }
        });
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        var MSUser = server.models.MSUser;
        MSUser.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            done(null, user);
        });
    });


    async function signInComplete(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
        if (!profile.oid) {
            return done(new Error("No OID found in user profile."), null);
        }
        try {
            const user = await graph.getUserDetails(accessToken);
            if (user) {
                profile['email'] = user.mail ? user.mail.toLowerCase() : user.userPrincipalName.toLowerCase();
            }
        } catch (err) {
            done(err, null);
        }
        let oauthToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(params);
        var AuthUser = server.models.AuthUser;
        var user = {};
        AuthUser.find({ where: { email: profile['email'] } }, function(err, au) {
            if (err) return done(err, null);
            if (au.length != 1) return done(new Error("User was not found with that email address."), null);
            user = au[0];
            const dataMsAuth = querystring.stringify({
                "created": new Date().toDateString(),
                "token_type": oauthToken.token.token_type,
                "expires_in": oauthToken.token.expires_in,
                "access_token": oauthToken.token.access_token,
                "scope": oauthToken.token.scope,
                "ext_expires_in": oauthToken.token.ext_expires_in,
                "refresh_token": oauthToken.token.refresh_token,
                "id_token": oauthToken.token.id_token,
                "expires_at": new Date(oauthToken.token.expires_at).toDateString()
            });
            const postMSAuth = {
                url: process.env.API_URL + "api/Companies/" + user.companyId + "/msauth",
                method: 'POST',
                body: dataMsAuth,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
            request(postMSAuth, function(err, resp, body) {
                if (err) return done(err, null);
                var MSUser = server.models.MSUser;
                var id = profile.oid;
                var msuser = { profile, oauthToken, oid: id, email: profile.email }
                MSUser.findById(id, function(err, msu) {
                    if (err) return done(err, null);
                    if (!msu) {
                        MSUser.create(msuser);
                    }
                });
                return done(null, msuser);
            });
        });
    }

    passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
            identityMetadata: `${process.env.OAUTH_AUTHORITY}${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
            clientID: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
            responseType: 'code id_token',
            responseMode: 'form_post',
            redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI,
            allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
            clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
            validateIssuer: false,
            passReqToCallback: false,
            scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES.split(' ')
        },
        signInComplete
    ));

    var app = express();
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(session({
        secret: process.env.BOOKINGS_LOOPBACK_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        unset: 'destroy'
    }));
    app.use("/result", express.static('client'));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(cors({
        origin: '*'
    }));

    erouter.get('/API/bookings/:companyid', getBookings());

    erouter.get('/auth/signin',
        function(req, res, next) {
            passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
                response: res,
                prompt: 'login',
                state: req.query.state,
                failureRedirect: process.env.WEBSITE_URL + 'settings?error=incorrect_request',
                successRedirect: process.env.WEBSITE_URL + 'settings?auth=success'
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    );

    erouter.post('/auth/callback',
        function(req, res, next) {
            passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
                response: res,
                failureRedirect: process.env.WEBSITE_URL + 'settings?error=permission_denied',
                successRedirect: process.env.WEBSITE_URL + 'settings?auth=success'
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    );

    app.use(erouter);
    server.use(app);
    server.use(router);
};
```

So my question is: "Is it possible to implement Microsoft Graph API in TypeScript using Loopback 4 or should I keep using Loopback 3 In JavaScript?"

Thanks in advance,

Billy Cottrell

Comment: I haven't tried with loopback4 nor i found samples on the same. Being said that i remember an [older thread talks about loopback with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476627/what-are-the-best-practises-for-generating-loopback-users-from-azure-active-dire) - so have a look at it.

Comment: Well as mentioned I have an existing working setup in Loopback 3 that is being used by a few customers already without any issues. Except Loopback 3 is in an EOL state and thus more and more high level issues are rising. I checked the Microsoft website, and they support Node.js and JavaScript, but no information is provided about support for TypeScript. Hence, the question if I should migrate to Loopback 4 or wait for future samples from either side (Microsoft or Loopback)

Comment: Like what creates a bigger risk staying in Loopback 3 or migrate to loopback 4 but keep the Microsoft service in a loopback 3 app that is being booted by loopback 4, and also does the latter work properly?